# I use countby() in query but how specific number of count to get? laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I work in Laravel, I get the students Ids and I count how many absents, but how I can select only students who have 2-time absents?

```php
App\StudentReport::pluck('absent')->collapse()->pluck('students')->collapse()->countby();
```

Output:

```php
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3095
     all: [
       "5d9ddb3512e5e17be04be12c" => 2,
       "5d9ddb3512e5e17be04be12d" => 2,
       "5da2411cf0d7276fab6ae8e5" => 13,
       "5da2411cf0d7276fab6ae8f0" => 13,
       "5da2411cf0d7276fab6ae8fd" => 1,
     ],
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter your data like this:

```
App\StudentReport::pluck('absent')->collapse()->pluck('students')->collapse()->countby()->filter(function($item){return $item ==2;});
```